# Weird starting and not starting for my 2005 Kia Sedona

Tags: starting, starter, kia, sedona

My 2005 Kia Sedona has a weird start and not start issue about every couple of weeks. It is currently doing it more often.  It also does this weird thing when I am trying to start it, it seems almost like it is seizing up.  As if it stops the turning of the starter.  OMG I have no idea how to say what it sounds like ahhhhh.  I just don't want to buy a new starter if it is something else.

Anyone else have this problem?

The battery is fully charged and the alternator is working so what could be the cause???

Thanks for the help ahead of time.

Comment: You'd need to catch it whenever it's cranking slow or not cranking and do a starter test. This usually involves watching how much load the starter puts on the system. As a rule of thumb battery voltage shouldn't drop below 9v while cranking.

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking ground terminals coming off your battery.

While this may not be the issue I can't tell you how many times I've found bad connection to be an issue with starters on my cars and for years it was something I consistently overlooked. If the connections are too loose or really corroded that can cause a huge resistance spike which will cut the amperage to the starter way down. That of course leads to insufficient cranking of the motor or sometimes even just a small click when it's just enough to push the starter into contact.

Anyway, just figured I'd throw that in.

Answer (score 0):

I would clean and tighten starter and battery connections. A load test of the starter would be the next thing to do.